# Excel look for most similar match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to solve this, but can't think of solution.

The problem is the following.

I have a list that includes ZIP codes and namesX and a second list that includes zip codes and namesX, but written differently.

Example:

ZIP | NAME | Random Number

*First List:*

**12345** | Hugo Schwarzenegger | 8325825

15478 | Ben Hauser          | 6546647

**12345** | Knurz Hill          | 7843456

*Second List:*

12345 | Hugo-SchwarzenEgger KG.T

...

In this example the random number in the first list, should get pasted behind the name in the second list:

12345 | Hugo-SchwarzenEgger KG.T | 8325825

What I tried so far is that I used =UPPER and =SUBSTITUTE to eleminate all the "unnecessary" characters like ("-","KG.T").
Combined ZIP and Name and used VLOOKUP for the first 5 charcter. Problem here is, that there are more results that have the same ZIP but a different name.

I can't get past the point to get the most similar text string in combination with the right ZIP

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdTfg.png)

Comment: If you were to provide more data from the Second List, you might find a pattern to look for, what other characters did you eliminate?

Comment: There is no ONE solution for this. You can implement that in many different ways depending on your source data and your needs. Therefore this question is pretty opinion based and might be off-topic. You need to find rules what a mach is and what no match is that you can "teach" your computer or you need a human who does it. Maybe you can implement an align algorithm like a [Sequence Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) or a similar one to align the data entries and then rate these alignments.

Comment: The [Longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) might help you too, or [Multiple String Alignment](http://www.barigozzi.eu/Barigozzi_Pin_msa.pdf). But you see this is no easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a direct comparison on the IDs, then use `InStr` to test for the first and last name. Note - you would need to change some of the columns around, also substitute a `lastrow` value in for the number 3 in the loops - but you didn't give us a lot of details on how your data's set up so I just made a hypothetical situation.

```
Sub Test()

Dim firstname As String, lastname As String, fullname As Variant
Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    fullname = Split(Range("B" & i).Value, " ")
    firstname = fullname(0)
    lastname = fullname(1)
    For j = 2 To lastrow2
        If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("F" & j).Value Then
            If InStr(LCase(Range("G" & j).Value), LCase(firstname)) > 0 Then
                If InStr(LCase(Range("G" & j).Value), LCase(lastname)) > 0 Then
                    Range("H" & j).Value = Range("C" & i).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

With some test data - before & after:

[image: BeforeAfter]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your example looks good. I added a picture in the original post  for better understanding.

I have to admit that I'm not yet used to VBA.
How do I make use of the code? So far I just inserted some code in a Medule (alt+f11, insert module) and ran it afterwards

Comment: @Knurz I edited my above example with your sample data - my macro works with it just fine.